# I am the odd one

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I am usually spread over five.
On rare occasions, like in 201, I occupy exactly 4.
But I am the only one that can never be in six.

Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> February

Because:

> It is usually spread in 5 weeks. In the year 201 it occupied 4 (if in your country the week starts on Sunday). However it can never occupy 6 weeks. All other months can.

Comment: Correct! If nobody would have guessed it I would have given a hint about the start of the week ;)

Comment: This is the reason that I couldn't figure it out, my week starts on monday so it wasn't the same in 201. I forgot about the week starting on sunday

Comment: how about year 2015....it still satisfies if week starts on sunday...:)

Comment: @user2408578 Yeah, there are probably more than a few years that satisfy this, but 201 makes it harder to guess that it refers to a year.

Comment: yep its hard to guess 201 as year....i was initially thinking about some pincodes here...:D nice thought though.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would have been guessed in a matter of seconds if I put 2015 there :P